# How to media query retina phone's landscape without using max-width?

Tags: media-queries, retina-display, screen-orientation, css

I'm testing my one page site on my Galaxy S3 (1280x720 px) and I can't seem to figure out what to have for max-width. I looked it up and couldn't find a current answer—-most clear answers were from "pre-retina". (Or should they still work..?)

With pixels devices changing so rapidly, is there any way to just target media query by device's orientatino?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Media queries also have an "orientation" feature which you can use in the query to detect portrait or landscape modes. The correct media query for your situation would be:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 720px) and (max-device-width: 1280px) and (orientation: landscape) {
/* insert styles here */
}
```

As a side note, I made a handy media query building tool with optional device presets (the one I used here is listed as "Galaxy Nexus, landscape") if you ever need to figure out other valid media queries: http://arcsec.ca/media-query-builder/

Answer (score 1):

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
 and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}
```

There are plenty more, check out http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just saw this. Will this work? For example, I want to target just the landscape of my phone, 1280x720px. If I use the code above for landscape, the min-width:321px sets a criterion that my phone can meet in portrait, too, no?

Comment: just change it to whatever you want